# Row total mismatch on credit memo page (magento version 2.4.3)

Tags: magento2, product, orders, totals, creditmemo

See this image it's the order page.
[image: Order page]

The highlighted product's calculations are correct.

See this image it's the credit memo page.
[image]

The highlighted product's calculations are incorrect.

Can you kindly take a look & advise what can be the issue of this mismatch of amounts ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?